# Ignoring special characters when comparing Strings

Tags: android

How can I ignore all special characters when comparing a String?

I have set up the code to ignore letter capitalization but i need to also ignore all other characters except from letters.

Here's my code so far

```
Collections.sort(MusicPlayerService.songNamesAll, new Comparator<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                            return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Tried filtering string characters before comparing?

Comment: `return s1.replaceAll("[-+.^:,]","").compareToIgnoreCase(s2.replaceAll("[-+.^:,]",""));`

Answer (score 0):

replace the characters other than alphanumeric with empty character, then compare the strings, like:

```
Collections.sort(MusicPlayerService.songNamesAll, new Comparator<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                     s1 = s1.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+","");
                     s2 = s2.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+","");
                     return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
                    }
                });
```